# Textbox does not update when IF condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, where the input box with id volumetric_weight is updated on keyup.
But, the second textbox with id volumetric_price does not update even though I believe I wrote it correctly.

Is there any mistake that I assigned their values as variables?
I dont understand.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#quantity, #length, #width, #height, #weight').keyup(function () {
         $('#volumetric_weight').val($('#length').val()*$('#width').val()*$('#height').val()*$('#quantity').val()/5000);

         var kila = $('#weight').val();
         var vol_kila = $('#volumetric_weight').val();

             if ( vol_kila > kila){
    $('#volumetric_price').val("443434324324");
}

     });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Strings in the if condition, you should convert these values to Numeric before comparing them.

```
var kila = +$('#weight').val();
var vol_kila = +$('#volumetric_weight').val();
```

Should solve your issue.